# Dynamic JTable size by number of rows

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable, jscrollbar

I kept on searching and nothing shows a good answer, I'm a bit new to the in depth parts of Java, so just asking.. How to resize or dynamically resize the `JTable` depending on its rows, instead of having a vertical scrollbar?

My method (not working):

After I add data into the table I then resize the table by its parent `JScrollPane`, since table resize automatically with its rows, but scroll pane doesn't but rather just stays the same before data was added. I've already tried these methods:

```
itemTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(...);
jScrollPane.setPreferredSize(...);//using the itemTable width and height
jScrollPane.setSize(...);//using the itemTable width and height
```

Still nothing works, can someone help me? Or maybe other solutions?

Comment: *"How to resize or dynamically resize the `JTable` depending on its rows, instead of having a vertical scrollbar?"* ... ***Why?*** I have a few other questions if you can convince me that it is a good idea to toss aside a technique ('use a scroll pane') which would be the path of least surprise for the user and has been successfully implemented in tens of thousands of GUIs over the decades.

Comment: The reason is, I'm trying to print a panel with a table on it for much easier and organize display of items, so I want the table to show all its rows, because we can't scroll on the paper.

Comment: Producing a paper report is a totally different process from producing a GUI.  For the GUI, use a JScrollPane.  For the paper report, use a report writer library, or [create the report](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html) yourself, considering each sheet of paper as the location of a BufferedImage.

Comment: Don't attempt to set the preferred size of Swing components!!! It is the job of the layout manager to set a components size/location. If you change the preferred scrollable viewport size, then you need to `revalidate()` the parent panel containing the scrollpane.   Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67506793/reset-jtable-depending-on-content-number-of-rows/67522733#67522733 for an example to get you started.